# Remove elements in an arraylist that exist in another arraylist

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

i have 2 array list, dateListDead and dateListNotMinggu. Both is DateTime List of Array. This is the ilustration of the date value in list of array
[The arrayList value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRq9q.png)

**its supposed to remove specific element that exist in other array list.**

so far i tried, this code it's not working.

```
 Dim d, x As Integer
 For x = 0 To dateListDead.Count - 1
    For d = 0 To dateListNotMinggu.Count - 1
        If dateListNotMinggu(d) = dateListDead(x) Then
               dateListNotMinggu.RemoveAt(d)
        End If
    Next
 Next
```

the error is : index out of range. how could it be ? i define the parameter of end looping base on arraylist.count -1

Comment: Firstly, it's not 2004 any more so you should not be using an `ArrayList` at all.  Since VB 2005, you should be using the `List(Of T)`.  If you want to store `DateTime` values then you should use a `List(Of DateTime)`.

Comment: Also, make sure to debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint, step through it line by line and actually look at the values as they are compared.  It's quite possible that you are assuming that two values are the same when they are not, e.g. they differ by milliseconds.  It certainly wouldn't be the first time I've seen that.  If you don't know how top debug, start learning [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It's a disgrace how often people claim to be teaching people how to program but don't teach the essential skill of debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main is that you are using a `For` loop from the first index to the last index but you don't account for the change of index when you remove a value.  If there might be multiple values then you should start and the end rather than the beginning.  In that case, removing an item won't affect the indexes of the items you are yet to test.  If there can only be one match then you should be exiting the loop when you find one.

Either way, while you don't have to, I would suggest using a `For Each` loop on the outside.  If you want to perform an action for each item in a list then that's exactly what a `For Each` loop is for.  Only use a `For` loop if you need to use the loop counter for something other than accessing each item in turn.

For multiple matches:

```
For Each dateDead As Date In dateListDead
    For i = dateListNotMinggu.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If CDate(dateListNotMinggu(i)) = dateDead Then
            dateListNotMinggu.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

For a single match:

```
For Each dateDead As Date In dateListDead
    For i = 0 To dateListNotMinggu.Count - 1
        If CDate(dateListNotMinggu(i)) = dateDead Then
            dateListNotMinggu.RemoveAt(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Note that I have also cast the `Date` values as that type for comparison, which is required with `Option Strict On`.  `Option Strict` is `Off` by default but you should always turn it `On` because it will help you write better code by focusing on data types.

Also, the code above would work with a `List(Of Date)` as well as an `ArrayList` but the casts would not be required with a `List(Of Date)`.  That's one of the advantages of using a generic `List(Of T)` over an `ArrayList`, which paces no restrictions on what it can contain.

If you really must use a `For` loop because that's what your homework assignment says then it would look like this:

```
For i = 0 To dateListDead.Count - 1
    For j = dateListNotMinggu.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If CDate(dateListNotMinggu(j)) = CDate(dateListDead(i)) Then
            dateListNotMinggu.RemoveAt(j)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

and this:

```
For i = 0 To dateListDead.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To dateListNotMinggu.Count - 1
        If CDate(dateListNotMinggu(j)) = CDate(dateListDead(i)) Then
            dateListNotMinggu.RemoveAt(j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Note that it is convention to use `i` as a first option for a loop counter, then `j` for the first nested loop, then `k` for the second nested loop.  You should only use something else if you have good reason to do so.  Remember that the loop counter doesn't represent the value in the list but rather its index.  That's why you use `i` for **i**ndex and not `d` for **d**ate or the like.

EDIT:

As per Jimi's comment below, the way this would usually be tackled is with a simple LINQ query.  If you were using LINQ then you definitely wouldn't be using an `ArrayList` but rather a `List(Of Date)`.  In that case, the code would look like this:

```
dateListNotMinggu = dateListNotMinggu.Except(dateListDead).ToList()
```

If you were completely insane and wanted to use LINQ and `ArrayLists` then this would work:

```
dateListNotMinggu = New ArrayList(dateListNotMinggu.Cast(Of Date)().
                                                    Except(dateListDead.Cast(Of Date)()).
                                                    ToArray())
```

Take note that, as I replied in the comments, using LINQ will generate a new list, rather than changing the existing one.

Comment: You may think it goes *out of scope* here, but also a `dateListNotMinggu.Except(dateListDead)` could be mentioned.

Comment: @Jimi, that was my first thought but, as you suggest, is probably out of scope. I'd generally use that in my own code but I suspect that this is homework and thus it would probably be wrong to use LINQ. I could be wrong about that but it certainly smells that way. The other potential issue is that `Except` will generate a new filtered list, rather than remove items from the original list. In some cases that may not be an issue but it may be in others. I might add it for completeness though.

Comment: thanks in advance @jmchilhinney, i got the point why we should loop in reverse. Great explanation. Also with the List(of Date), why do we need to use CDate? on my experience, it still work without CDate, because before data assigned in arraylist, i was convert.toDateTime each one of it, but thank you anywy to the better explanation and the help

Comment: If you use `List(Of Date)` instead of `ArrayList` then you don't need the casts.  As I said in there somewhere: *" the casts would not be required with a `List(Of Date)`"*.  As I also said, the code will still work with the casts but they are superfluous.